# How to achieve fixed width spacing between multiple images centred horizontally and vertically

Tags: html, css

This [codepen](https://codepen.io/simonhrogers/pen/WJJVgL) will make clear what I am trying to do:

HTML:

```
  <div class="slider-container">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">
          <img src="https://images.robertharding.com/preview/RM/RH/VERTICAL/983-675.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="padding-cell"></div>
        <div class="cell">
          <img src="https://images.robertharding.com/preview/RM/RH/VERTICAL/983-675.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="padding-cell"></div>
        <div class="cell">
          <img src="https://images.robertharding.com/preview/RM/RH/VERTICAL/983-675.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.slider-container {
  left: 4.5em; 
  right: 4.5em; 
  position: fixed;
  top: 4.5em;
  height: calc(100vh - 9em);
}

.slider-container .table {
    display: table;
    height: inherit;
    width: 100%;
}

.slider-container .table .row {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
    height: inherit;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.slider-container .table .row .padding-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  height: inherit;
  width: 1.5em; 
}

.slider-container .table .row .cell {
  display: table-cell;
  height: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.slider-container .table .row .cell img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/simonhrogers/pen/WJJVgL

When the aspect ratio of the image is particularly tall, or the screen particularly squashed, the gaps between each image will begin to stretch much wider than the width of the specified padding cell between them. How can I prevent this behaviour so that the images are always separated by just the width of the padding cell?

I still need the images to shrink if too close to the top/bottom or sides of the screen; as I have here, but with a fixed-width gap between them instead of that changing too.

Desired:
[image]

Undesired:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired behavior by doing some minor changes in your code:
First set `width:100%` for your image.
Second set a fixed padding in your class `padding-cell` in unit `px` or `rem`

```css
.slider-container {
  left: 4.5em;
  right: 4.5em;
  position: fixed;
  top: 4.5em;
  height: calc(100vh - 9em);
}

.slider-container .table {
  display: table;
  height: inherit;
  width: 100%;
}

.slider-container .table .row {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.slider-container .table .row .padding-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  height: inherit;
  width: 20px;
}

.slider-container .table .row .cell {
  display: table-cell;
  height: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.slider-container .table .row .cell img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        <img src="https://images.robertharding.com/preview/RM/RH/VERTICAL/983-675.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="padding-cell"></div>
      <div class="cell">
        <img src="https://images.robertharding.com/preview/RM/RH/VERTICAL/983-675.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="padding-cell"></div>
      <div class="cell">
        <img src="https://images.robertharding.com/preview/RM/RH/VERTICAL/983-675.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Although you can achieve the layout more easily with `flexbox`.

Comment: Thanks but the images now squash themselves rather than maintaining proportions if they become too small for the screen; is there a way to avoid, or would this be doable with flexbox?

Comment: Sorry, I can't get you. As the size of the screen reduce image also get reduce in their size but in aspect ratio of their original size until you reduce the height of the viewport less then its width. If you wish to maintain both height and width aspect ration in every situation then you must center align your image grid. so that the space left and right side from screen increases but the space between images remain intact